# Name cannot be null or empty

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I am trying to use identity with DB first and I followed the this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elfqejow5hM. I am getting an error "Name cannot be null or empty." I don't have any column Name. And also does not called the "OnModelCreating".

this is my application user class

```
public class MyUser : IdentityUser<long, MyLogin, MyUserRole, MyClaim>
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class MyUserRole : IdentityUserRole<long> { }

public class MyRole : IdentityRole<long, MyUserRole> { }

public class MyClaim : IdentityUserClaim<long> { }

public class MyLogin : IdentityUserLogin<long> { }
```

this is my onmodelcreating code

```
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyUser>().ToTable("AspNetUser");
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyUserRole>().ToTable("AspNetRole");
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyRole>().ToTable("AspNetRole");
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyClaim>().ToTable("AspNetUserClaim");
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyLogin>().ToTable("AspNetUserLogin");

        modelBuilder.Entity<MyUser>().Property(r => r.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyRole>().Property(r => r.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyClaim>().Property(r => r.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

and my register post method is

```
          var manager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<MyUser>();
            var user = new MyUser()
            {
                Email = model.Email,
                EmailConfirmed = false,
                PhoneNumberConfirmed = false,
                TwoFactorEnabled = false,
                LockoutEndDateUtc = DateTime.Now,
                LockoutEnabled = false,
                AccessFailedCount = 0,
                UserName = model.userName
            };
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

Can any one help me the cause for the error.

Comment: Please add more details of your code and refer this too http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Now I edit my question with sample code @Eldho